# dropdown horizontal menubar compatible with jQueryUI and google maps

Tags: google-maps, drop-down-menu, menu

I have a strange situation (that is strange for me!)
My application uses jQueryUI modal div and simple google maps.
I need a horizontal dropdown menu and I tried countless of available dropdown menues but none of them work with the google map OR with the jQueryUI modal div.
I assume there are conflics in the .CSS or .js files.
Can anybody please point me towards a dropdown menu that will work with the google maps AND jQueryUI.
Any help is very much appreciated.
PS for me also JQueryUI and the google map do  not work on the same .php file.

Thanks,

Carly

Answer (score 0):

You can use this plugin - unless you need some **very** customized maps, it works great
[Google Maps jQuery Plugin](http://code.google.com/p/jquery-ui-map/).

For drop down menu's I love the iPod style menu released by the Filament Group.
You can grab it [here](http://www.filamentgroup.com/lab/jquery_ipod_style_and_flyout_menus/).

Let me know if there is any problem integrating all three. We have done this before so I know it works.

Cheers!

Comment: Varun, do you know how I can add more then 1 flat menu for example on the same page. (I guess this menu is directed towards iPhone development but I would like to use it on a for laptop developed page). Thanks

Comment: @Carly: Can you elucidate? According to me a flat menu is equal to a dropdownlist... What exactly do you need? Also, did the above solution work for you?

Comment: Varun Everything is (almost) OK. I was able to do what I needed with one exception (the above situation was solved).
The situation that I face right now is as following:
I created a Header.php file that has the drop down menu.
I bring the menu to all my other pages using require_once("Header.php"); The page that has the very simple Google map is not displayed correctly in IE7 (but is OK in Firefox) - the map is not displayed at all and there are errors.
Everything is OK even in IE7 when instead of require_once("Header.php"); I put the actual code of the Header.php in the page with the map.
The